# How can I know where the segment of memory is all Zero

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, memory

I mean, I malloc a segment of memory, maybe 1k maybe 20bytes..
assume the pointer is `pMem`
How can I know the content `pMem` refered is all `Zero` or `\0`
. I know `memcmp` but the second parameter should another memory address...
thanx

Answer (score 20):

As others have already suggested you probably want [memset](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/memset.html) or [calloc](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/calloc.html).

But if you actually do want to check if a memory area is all zero, you can compare it with itself but shifted by one.

```
bool allZero = pMem[0] == '\0' && !memcmp(pMem, pMem + 1, length - 1);
```

where length is the number of bytes you want to be zero.

Comment: Yes, call `memcmp` in its slower case (two buffers with different alignments), in order to do twice the necessary memory accesses, for a memory-bound task... What a good idea!

Comment: The sarcasm wasn't necessary, Pascal.

Comment: That's a really slower than simple for-loop.

Comment: To Kirill V. Lyadvinsky. Really? what if it is a big memory space? it's also slower?

Comment: @Rob Wasn't it? I'm sorry, I'm a little bit out of touch.

Comment: While clever, this answer is slower than necessary. A simple for-loop is the correct answer (be it hand-written or from `algorithm`). You *have* to look at each byte of memory to know it every byte of memory is 0. the only way that isn't true is if you can make assumptions like "If this byte is 0, the next 3 are". that is of course only an example and not present true in your situation.

Comment: Hi everyone, and thanks for all the interesting comments! When I wrote the comment I didn't care about performance - I thought the max length was about 1K and typically about 20 bytes. I think someone should profile both methods for lots of short strings, and then again for some longer ones. I think it can't be that hard to do, and would make for an interesting experiment! I would do it myself but I have to work. I hope someone can do this and post the results. Looking forward to seeing it!

Comment: @Mark: No need to profile, really. Your code for sure checks each memory location twice, and probably does all sorts of nasty things with cache while it's at it.

Comment: You're ignoring the processor's own cache. You can't really guess this sort of thing, you have to measure it. It should be straight-forward, I jsut don't have time now. If no-one else does it, I'll do it when I get home.

Comment: Hmm... I've done some preliminary measurements, and the memcmp method appears to be very slightly faster than the simple looping on my machine, but right now I'm using a non-standard PC. If we want to know what's fastest (I don't it's going to be the bottleneck in his program anyway) we really should test this properly with benchmark tests rather than just guessing and making assumptions.

Comment: @Mark Sorry if I sounded sarcastic. I am convinced that `memcmp(p,p+1,size-1)` is good enough, I was just shocked to see comments here and in other answers that revealed some sort of "it's O(1) because it's a library call, the for-loop takes longer because it has to read the buffer" reasoning.

Comment: It's OK. I was surprised at the opposite: lots of people here seem to think that the *only* way to access memory is one byte at a time.

Comment: I've written my own benchmark (posted in an answer). Interested to know how it compares with yours, Mark. I haven't yet got memcmp to go very fast...

Comment: My objection to this is that, while it's clever, it's not immediately obvious what it's doing.  A `for` loop would be much clearer, in my opinion.  Cleverness is no substitute for clarity.

Comment: The worst is that it forces one of the reads to be unaligned, so even a full-word-read optimization would suffer. Anyway, no -1 because it's cute.

Comment: How would this perform if we allowed better word alignment by memcmp'ing against pMem+4 or pMem+8 (and handling the borderline cases)?

Answer (score 14):

Since Mark's answer has provoked some controversy:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef count
    #define count 1000*1000
#endif
#ifndef blocksize
    #define blocksize 1024
#endif

int checkzeros(char *first, char *last) {
    for (; first < last; ++first) {
        if (*first != 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int zeros = 0;

    #ifdef EMPTY
        /* empty test loop */
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            char *p = malloc(blocksize);
            if (*p == 0) ++zeros;
            free(p);
        }
    #endif

    #ifdef LOOP
        /* simple check */
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            char *p = malloc(blocksize);
            if (checkzeros(p, p + blocksize)) ++zeros;
            free(p);
        }
    #endif

    #ifdef MEMCMP
        /* memcmp check */
        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            char *p = malloc(blocksize);
            if (*p == 0 && !memcmp(p, p + 1, blocksize - 1)) ++zeros;
            free(p);
        }
    #endif

    printf("%d\n", zeros);
    return 0;
}
```

Results (cygwin, Windows XP, Core 2 Duo T7700 at 2.4 GHz):

```
$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DEMPTY && time ./cmploop
1000000

real    0m0.500s
user    0m0.405s
sys     0m0.000s

$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DLOOP && time ./cmploop
1000000

real    0m1.203s
user    0m1.233s
sys     0m0.000s

$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DMEMCMP && time ./cmploop
1000000

real    0m2.859s
user    0m2.874s
sys     0m0.015s
```

So, the memcmp is taking approximately (2.8 - 0.4) / (1.2 - 0.4) = 3 times as long, for me. It'd be interesting to see other people's results - all my malloced memory is zeroed, so I'm getting the worst-case time for each comparison, always.

With smaller blocks (and more of them) the comparison time is less significant, but memcmp is still slower:

```
$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DEMPTY -Dblocksize=20 -Dcount=10000000 && time ./cmploop
10000000

real    0m3.969s
user    0m3.780s
sys     0m0.030s

$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DLOOP -Dblocksize=20 -Dcount=10000000 && time ./cmploop
10000000

real    0m4.062s
user    0m3.968s
sys     0m0.015s

$ gcc-4 cmploop.c -o cmploop -pedantic -Wall -O2 -DMEMCMP -Dblocksize=20 -Dcount=10000000 && time ./cmploop
10000000

real    0m4.391s
user    0m4.296s
sys     0m0.015s
```

I am slightly surprised by this. I expected memcmp to at least compete, since I expect it to be inlined and to be optimised for small sizes known at compile time. Even changing it so that it tests an int at the start and then 16 bytes of memcmp, to avoid the unaligned worst case, doesn't speed it up much.

Comment: +1 for actually measuring! I'll try to make my own benchmarks later when I have time. PS: what CPU/OS are you using? Maybe this could make a difference too.

Comment: same goes for memcpy, by the way... :(

Comment: I'm not surprised, as the memcmp may not be optimized for the given platform.  I found that one compiler manufacturer didn't use some native processor capabilities, such as the load multiple registers in the ARM processor.  If you unroll the loop, you will get better performance, as you divide the overhead over the number of instructions.

Comment: Well, I said I was "a bit" surprised. This is gcc-4 on x86, and I've seen `memcpy` outrageously optimised as an intrinsic in other situations. So I was hoping it would do something impressive with memcmp too, I just don't know what.

Comment: Example of "outrageous": `int i = <something>; int j; memcpy(&j, &i, sizeof(int)); return j;`. The memcpy is optimised to a no-op, it just uses EAX for i in the first place. OK, there's no chance for register trickery in this problem, and no redundant variables to eliminate, but I was hoping the kind of mind capable of that would also be capable of doing a 16 byte same-alignment memcmp in 4 word comparisons (plus a little bit of work to identify the sign of the difference if it differs). Or something.

Comment: OK, I used your testbed now and it's close for 10M * 100bytes, but the loop wins. I also get that the gap widens as the length increases. The reason you always get zeros is that you keep getting the exact same pointer. It might be more realistic to ask for differing amounts of memory and/or not free them immediately.

Comment: Yes, and/or write some data to them before freeing. See whether the malloc implementation is clearing them before allocating, or whether it's only zeros because it's fresh new memory for the process. Almost anything should be incredibly fast if the data *isn't* zero, because it can bail out early (although see Per Ekman's answer for one that doesn't, and benefits in the zero case).

Comment: I just tried it using MS VC++ 2008 compiler: the array returned isn't all zero, so you get almost identical times for both methods.

Comment: Can you try gcc's auto-vectorization? It might be as easy as `-O3 -msse2`.

Comment: While memcmp may be optimized, it's still a fundamentally inefficient way to perform this operation. We're interested in element-wise comparisons of two buffers. We're interested in whether all the elements in one buffer matches a single scalar value. Adding false memory dependencies is rarely the way to get good performance.

Comment: Interesting. On my machine, for a 1Gb memory block filles with zeros, `memcmp` trick is ~4 times faster than a dumb loop comparing individual chars, and ~3 times faster than a loop comparing int-sized chunks. This is VC++2010 x86, compiled with `/O2`.

Comment: On a buffer _not_ filled with zeros (random garbage from `new char[]`), `memcmp` is still almost 2x faster than loop over chars, but is exactly the same as loop over ints.

Comment: ... however, I was using somewhat different call, specifically measuring performance of specific sections of blocks inside the process rather than the execution time of the process from start to finish. I used `GetTickCount`, which, given durations of 700+ milliseconds in best cases (for 1Gb), is accurate enough.

Comment: Okay, turns out there was a typo in the test that skewed the result. I've also rewritten it to use `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get more precise value. Now with the fixed test, given the same input and environment, I get: "memcmp: 823ms;
charloop: 1303ms;
intloop: 814ms" - for random garbage memory block; "memcmp: 491ms
charloop: 985ms;
intloop: 479ms" - for pre-zeroed memory block.

Comment: So at a reasonable approximation, memcmp is keeping pace with the intloop. I'm not hugely surprised - a dumb memcmp only does twice as many memory loads as the dump loop, and because of our parameters, those loads are from adjacent words. So all memcmp should really need is fewer cache misses than the loop (better cache pre-fetching than /O2 achieves), or to vectorise to bigger than a word. I guess either gcc is missing a trick with memcmp, or VC++ is missing a trick with the loop optimisation. Or both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872156/1876630#1876630 I made a more thorough benchmark; on my system, GCC's memcmp is in the same ballpark as all the other byte-by-byte access methods.  Disassembly suggests that lack of alignment is preventing any further optimizations.

Answer (score 9):

If you're testing it, and then only going to use it if it's zero, then be aware you have a race-condition, because the method suggested by @Mark Byers doesn't have an atomic test/set operation. It'll be hard to get the logic correct in this case.

If you want to zero it if it's not already zero, then just set it to zero as that will be faster.

Answer (score 7):

C++ solution:

```
bool all_zeroes = 
  (find_if( pMem, pMem+len, bind2nd(greater<unsigned char>(), 0)) == (pMem+len));
```

Answer (score 5):

As you've noted, `memcmp` compares one block of memory to another. If you had another block of memory that you *already knew* was all zero, then you could use that reference block to compare with your candidate block to see whether they match.

It sounds like you don't have another block of memory, though. You just have one, and you want to know whether it's all zero. The standard libraries don't provide such a function, but it's easy to write your own:

```
bool is_all_zero(char const* mem, size_t size)
{
  while (size-- > 0)
    if (*mem++)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

If you want to allocate a new block of memory and have it be all zero right away, then use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. If you have a block of memory that you want to set to all zero, then use `memset` or `std::fill`.

Comment: If it is a huge memory. this comparision takes a lot of time

Comment: @Macroideal Unless there is special support from the hardware, checking if a buffer contains all zeros requires reading the buffer. There is no way around it. At least in this answer, the buffer is read only once.

Comment: Pascal Cuoq: Have you measured the performance or are you just guessing? If you've measured it, please post results - I would be very interested to see. It doesn't seem obvious to me that the memcpy solution will have to hit the memory twice - the processor has a cache too, and that is much faster than memory. I'd be very interested to see the results, regardless of whice solution is better. Plus I think it's a standard best-practice to measure performance, not guess.

Comment: Pascal Couq: I've thrown together a quick test and it shows that this method is **not** significantly faster on my hardware for 10M allocations of 100 bytes, even when the function is changed to a macro and inlined. I'll post more detailed results when I have time (in about 8 hours from now).

Comment: (And in both cases, the performance impact was negligible - the main performance hit came from the calls to malloc.)

Comment: @Mark Byers: It may not physically touch memory twice. But it *will* cause additional dependencies. Each comparison has to wait for two values to be retrieved, not just one. Even if they both have to be retrieved from cache (which will be the usual case), that is still slower than comparing one object in memory against a known compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3):

For large buffers:

```
typedef int tNativeInt;  // __int64 on 64 bit platforms with 32 bit ints

// test most of the buffer using CPU Word size
tNativeInt * ptr = reinterpret_cast<tNativeInt *>(buffer);
tNativeInt * end = ptr + bufSize / sizeof(tNativeInt);
for(;ptr < end;++ptr)
  if (*ptr != 0)
    return false;

// check remainder
char * ptrc = reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr);
char * endc = ptrc + bufSize % sizeof(tNativeInt);
for(; ptrc<endc; ++ptrc)
  if (*ptrc != 0)
    return false;
```

Remarks:
The core optimizations testing full CPU words - reading one is generally as expensive as a single byte.

The code assumes the buffer is well aligned (i.e. the address is a multiple of the CPU Word size). If not, a block similar to "remainder" needs to be put in front of the block test.

The additional code will of course be slower for small buffers - however, in this case one commonly assumes that these short durations don't matter.

If you prefer you can of course replace the loops with std::find_if.

---

**Performance: 1: 3.9**

(VS 2008, /Ox /Ot,  2,47 +/- 0,11  vs. 0,63 +/- 0,19, for 10000 repeats over 256000 bytes, 
statistics over 15 repeats first removed)

Discussion: From my experience analyzing C/C++ to assembly, I *wouldn't* expect a compiler to do this optimization - because it is a pessimization for small `size`, and optimization possibilities of that type are few and far between. The factor of roughly 4 confirms the assumpotion - as does looking at the disassembly.

Also, the total time is negligible for most applications, a cache miss will be far worse and affect both versions the same.

[edit] for the fun of it:

**Overlapping memcmp clocks in at 1:1.4**, which is vastly better than the single byte check (surprised me a little).

Note that the misaligned read makes that strongly platform dependent.

Comment: I would expect the compiler to do that optimization (not reading one
byte at a time, but reading words). Have you seen this buy you 
any performance with -O2 for instance?

Comment: This relies on the fact that buffer is a return from malloc. Which is stated in the question, so fair enough, just be aware that you can't use just any old char* for buffer, because it might not be aligned. Also, it's undefined to reinterpret_cast to tNativeInt* and dereference, but we can probably assume a platform which supports that.

Comment: @Per: See update.  ... @Steve: premainder implementation is left as an excercise for the reader ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872156/1876630#1876630 I see a roughly 1:4 or 1:8 improvement depending on 32-bit or 64-bit using raw assembly, and only around a 1:4 improvement in C either way.

Comment: ephemient: are you using __int64 explicitely? sizeof(int) == 32 bit is a common choice also on 64 bit platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use calloc if you want all 0s in the memory you allocate

Answer (score 2):

If you need the memory to be zero, just `memset()` it to zero; it's a waste of time to check whether it's zero first, because it probably isn't and you'll end up doing more work overall, checking and then setting.

However, if you really want to efficiently check a region of memory to see if it's all zero, you can `memcmp()` it against something else that's *known* to be all zero.  You could allocate and zero one chunk of memory, for example, and then keep a pointer to it for use in comparing against other chunks of memory.

Comment: memcmp against a preallocated region wouldn't be very efficient. It'd require two memory reads per address you want to compare. +1 for the first point though

Comment: Why would a memcmp - involving two reads - be efficient? (Fast enough, maybe, but not efficient)

Comment: It's not terribly efficient, but it's correct and portable.  One could also use a loop and check the value of each byte, but a `memcmp()` implementation may use a more efficient approach, comparing whole machine words rather than individual bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Another C++ solution, slightly simpler than Kirill's. It is somewhat less efficient, though, as it traverses the entire sequence even when that sequence contains a non-zero element.

```
bool all_zeroes = std::count(pMem, pMem + length, 0) == length;
```

Comment: not bad, but slightly overkill when the first byte already contains zero.

Comment: xtofl, you mean non-zero. And yes, it will be asymptotically worse than the optimal algorithm in average case (it has the same worst-case complexity though). I actually noted the efficiency issue in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Poking around with Steve Jessops code for fun I found this variant

```
int checkzeros(char *f, char *l) {
        char a = 0;
        while (f < l) {
                a |= *f++;
        }
        if (a) {
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

to be about 50% faster (no branches in the core loop). All bugs are mine.

[Edit]: As Steve points out, this version has a good worst case and a terrible
best case (since they are the same). Only use it if a completely zeroed buffer
is the only case that needs to be fast.

Comment: Good point - this version is good if you expect checkzeros to be true, and bad if the buffer contains random data. In that case, my loop will bail out after one byte with probability 255/256, whereas yours always runs to the end, so I'd hope mine is more than 50% faster.

Answer (score 2):

More benchmarks:

Roughly based on Steve Jessop's sample. 
I've tested the following:

- Naive memcmp (allocate a separate block of zeros, and compare against that)
- "clever" memcmp ( compare the block against itself, shifted once)
- `std::find_if`
- A simple loop checking each byte

None of these make any assumptions about the array, and simply accept and work on an array of chars.

Finally, I made a fifth version, which casts the array to ints, and compares those. (This one obviously assumes that the size of the array is divisible by `sizeof(int)`, so it is less general. But I added it to demonstrate that working with a reasonable chunk size is a much more useful optimization than messing around with memcpy and byte-wise comparisons.

Oh, and note that I just slapped this test together quickly, and I used one of Windows' timers because I'm lazy. :)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

#include <windows.h>

enum {
    count = 1000*1000,
    blocksize = 1024
};

bool test_simple_loop(char* p){
    for (int i = 0; i < blocksize; ++i) {
        if (p[i] != 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

bool test_memcmp_clever(char* p){
    return *p == 0 && memcmp(p, p + 1, blocksize - 1) == 0;
}
bool test_memcmp_naive(char* p, char* ref){
    return memcmp(p, ref, blocksize) == 0;
}

struct cmp {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T& x) {
        return x != 0;
    }
};
bool test_find_if(char* p){
    return std::find_if(p, p+blocksize, cmp()) == p+blocksize;
}

bool test_find_if_big(int* p){
    return std::find_if(p, p+blocksize, cmp()) == p+blocksize;
}

int main() {

    bool res = true;

    char *p = new char[blocksize];
    char *ref = new char[blocksize];

    std::fill(ref, ref+blocksize, 0);
    std::fill(p, p+blocksize, 0); // ensure the worst-case scenario, that we have to check the entire buffer. This will also load the array into CPU cache so the first run isn't penalized

    DWORD times[5];
    DWORD start;

    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        res &= test_memcmp_naive(p, ref);
    }
    times[0] = GetTickCount() - start;
    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        res &= test_memcmp_clever(p);
    }
    times[1] = GetTickCount() - start;
    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        res &= test_find_if(p);
    }
    times[2] = GetTickCount() - start;
    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        res &= test_simple_loop(p);
    }
    times[3] = GetTickCount() - start;
    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        res &= test_find_if_big(reinterpret_cast<int*>(p));
    }
    times[4] = GetTickCount() - start;

    delete[] p;
    delete[] ref;

    printf("%d\n", res);
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", times[0], times[1], times[2], times[3], times[4]);
}
```

My results are: (in milliseconds, for a million runs)

```
Naive memcmp: 546
"Clever" memcmp: 530
`find_if<char>`: 1466
Simple loop: 1358
`find_if<int`>: 343
```

I think the takeaway point is pretty clear:
Anything that does a bytewise comparison is slow. Really slow. Memcmp does more or less ok, but it's far from perfect. It is too general to be optimal.

The most efficient way to solve this problem is to process as much data at a time as possible. `char` is just silly. `int` is a good start, but 64- or 128-bit reads would probably perform far better still.

Comment: Would be interesting to know the time of memset to 0 aswell.

Comment: I'd expect that to be by far the fastest. You save all the comparisons and dependencies on memory accesses.

Comment: jalf: +1 for taking the time to do this - it's fascinating to me that something so simple as testing for zero can create so much discussion! But I would like to know why do you claim that memcmp is the slower than a simple loop when your own tests show it to be faster? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I meant that it was slower than a simple loop with a larger word size. `std::find_if` is basically the same algorithm as a simple loop, so I used that as a representative of "simpler loop with larger word size".

Answer (score 1):

`repe.S`:

```
.globl repe_scasb
repe_scasb:
#if defined(__i386__)
        push   %edi
        mov    $0x0,%al
        mov    0xc(%esp),%ecx
        mov    0x8(%esp),%edi
        sub    %edi,%ecx
        repe scasb
        pop    %edi
        sete   %al
        ret
#elif defined(__amd64__)
        mov    $0x0,%al
        mov    %rsi,%rcx
        sub    %rdi,%rcx
        repe scasb
        sete   %al
        ret
#else
#  error "repe_scasb not defined for current architecture"
#endif

.globl repe_scas
repe_scas:
#if defined(__i386__)
        push   %edi
        mov    $0x0,%eax
        mov    0xc(%esp),%edx
        mov    0x8(%esp),%edi
        sub    %edi,%edx
repe_scas4:
        test   $0x3,%di
        jnz    repe_scas2
        cmp    $0x4,%edx
        jl     repe_scas2
        mov    %edx,%ecx
        shr    $0x2,%ecx
        repe scasl
        jne    repe_scas0
        and    $0x3,%edx
repe_scas2:
        test   $0x1,%di
        jnz    repe_scas1
        cmp    $0x2,%edx
        jl     repe_scas1
        scasw
        jnz    repe_scas0
        sub    $0x2,%edx
        jmp    repe_scas4
repe_scas1:
        test   %edx,%edx
        jz     repe_scas0
        scasb
        jnz    repe_scas0
        sub    $0x1,%edx
        jmp    repe_scas4
repe_scas0:
        pop    %edi
        sete   %al
        ret
#elif defined(__amd64__)
        mov    $0x0,%eax
        sub    %rdi,%rsi
repe_scas8:
        test   $0x7,%di
        jnz    repe_scas4
        cmp    $0x8,%rsi
        jl     repe_scas4
        mov    %rsi,%rcx
        shr    $0x3,%rcx
        repe scasq
        jne    repe_scas0
        and    $0x7,%rsi
repe_scas4:
        test   $0x3,%di
        jnz    repe_scas2
        cmp    $0x4,%rsi
        jl     repe_scas2
        scasl
        jnz    repe_scas0
        sub    $0x4,%rsi
        jmp    repe_scas8
repe_scas2:
        test   $0x1,%di
        jnz    repe_scas1
        cmp    $0x2,%rsi
        jl     repe_scas1
        scasw
        jnz    repe_scas0
        sub    $0x2,%rsi
        jmp    repe_scas8
repe_scas1:
        test   %rsi,%rsi
        jz     repe_scas0
        scasb
        jnz    repe_scas0
        sub    $0x1,%rsi
        jmp    repe_scas8
repe_scas0:
        sete   %al
        ret
#else
#  error "repe_scas not defined for current architecture"
#endif
```

`test.c`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static int compar_double(const void *a, const void *b) {
    double diff = *(const double *)a - *(const double *)b;
    if (diff < 0) return -1;
    if (diff > 0) return 1;
    return 0;
}

static bool bit_or(const void *first, const void *last) {
    uint8_t a;
    for (a = 0; first < last; first = (const uint8_t *)first + 1)
        a |= *(const uint8_t *)first;
    return !a;
}

static bool use_memcmp(const void *first, const void *last) {
    return first >= last
        || !(((uint8_t *)first)[0]
        || memcmp(first, (const uint8_t *)first + 1,
            (const uint8_t *)last - (const uint8_t *)first - 1));
}

static bool check_bytes(const void *first, const void *last) {
    while (first < last) {
        if (*(const uint8_t *)first) return false;
        first = (const uint8_t *)first + 1;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool check_aligned(const void *first, const void *last) {
    switch ((uintptr_t)first & 7) while (first < last) {
        case 0:
            if (last - first >= 8) {
                if (*(const uint64_t *)first) return false;
                first = (const uint64_t *)first + 1;
                continue;
            }
        case 4:
            if (last - first >= 4) {
                if (*(const uint32_t *)first) return false;
                first = (const uint32_t *)first + 1;
                continue;
            }
        case 2: case 6:
            if (last - first >= 2) {
                if (*(const uint16_t *)first) return false;
                first = (const uint16_t *)first + 1;
                continue;
            }
        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7:
            if (*(const uint8_t *)first) return false;
            first = (const uint8_t *)first + 1;
    }
    return true;
}

bool repe_scasb(const void *, const void *);
bool repe_scas(const void *, const void *);

static const struct {
    const char name[16];
    bool (*fn)(const void *, const void *);
} functions[] = {
    { "bit_or", bit_or },
    { "use_memcmp", use_memcmp },
    { "check_bytes", check_bytes },
    { "check_aligned", check_aligned },
    { "repe_scasb", repe_scasb },
    { "repe_scas", repe_scas },
};

#define REPS 999
#define BYTECYCLES 0xFFFF
void time_functions(const char *s, const void *first, const void *last, bool expect) {
    unsigned i, cycles = BYTECYCLES / (last - first) + 1;
    char seps[sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions)];
    double times[sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions)][REPS];

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions); i++) {
        unsigned j;

        seps[i] = '/';
        for (j = 0; j < REPS; j++) {
            unsigned k;
            struct timespec start, finish;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
            for (k = 0; k < cycles; k++)
                if (functions[i].fn(first, last) != expect) seps[i] = '!';
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
            times[i][j] = ((finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                    (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 100000000.) / cycles;
        }
    }

    fputs(s, stdout);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions); i++) {
        qsort(times[i], REPS, sizeof(double), compar_double);
        printf("|%8.2e%c%8.2e", times[i][REPS / 4], seps[i], times[i][3 * REPS / 4]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static size_t sizes[] = {0x7, 0x7, 0x7, 0x7, 0x400, 0x1000, 0x100000};
static uint8_t storage[0x100000];

int main() {
    unsigned i, j, k;

    fputs("      ", stdout);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions); i++)
        printf(" |%16.16s", functions[i].name);
    fputs("\n-------", stdout);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(functions) / sizeof(*functions); i++)
        fputs("+-----------------", stdout);
    putc('\n', stdout);

    for (j = 0, k = 8; j < sizeof(sizes) / sizeof(*sizes); j++) {
        char test[8];
        if (k /= 2) snprintf(test, sizeof(test), "0x%zX+%u", sizes[j], k);
        else snprintf(test, sizeof(test), "0x%zX", sizes[j]);
        printf("%-7.7s|\n", test);

        memset(storage + k, 0, sizes[j]);
        time_functions("  zero ", storage + k, storage + k + sizes[j], true);

        storage[k + sizes[j] - 1] = 1;
        time_functions("  last ", storage + k, storage + k + sizes[j], false);

        storage[k + sizes[j] / 2] = 1;
        time_functions("  half ", storage + k, storage + k + sizes[j], false);

        memset(storage + k, ~0, sizes[j]);
        time_functions("  first", storage + k, storage + k + sizes[j], false);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS ?= -g -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra
LIBS = -lrt
SRC := test.c repe.S
all: test32 test64
test32: $(SRC)
        $(CC) -m32 $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
test64: $(SRC)
        $(CC) -m64 $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
time: time32 time64
time32: test32
        ./test32
time64: test64
        ./test64
.PHONY: all time time32 time64
```

Instead of just the average, this test shows the 1st quartile and 3rd quartile of time taken, but it seems the system was fairly consistent (runs varying within ±2%).

```
$ make time
cc -m32 -g -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra  -o test32 test.c repe.S -lrt
./test32
       |          bit_or |      use_memcmp |     check_bytes |   check_aligned |      repe_scasb |       repe_scas
-------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
0x7+4  |
  zero |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.11e-07|1.66e-07/1.68e-07|1.35e-07/1.74e-07|1.83e-07/1.86e-07|2.00e-07/2.06e-07
  last |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.12e-07|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|1.18e-07/1.18e-07|1.83e-07/1.85e-07|1.83e-07/1.85e-07
  half |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.79e-07/1.84e-07|7.42e-08/7.42e-08|6.98e-08/6.98e-08|1.57e-07/1.59e-07|1.39e-07/1.40e-07
  first|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|6.11e-08/6.11e-08|4.81e-08/4.81e-08|6.98e-08/6.99e-08|1.22e-07/1.27e-07|1.39e-07/1.42e-07
0x7+2  |
  zero |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.11e-07|1.66e-07/1.71e-07|1.31e-07/1.57e-07|1.83e-07/1.85e-07|2.00e-07/2.06e-07
  last |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.14e-07|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|1.22e-07/1.24e-07|1.83e-07/1.88e-07|1.83e-07/1.83e-07
  half |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.79e-07/1.80e-07|7.42e-08/7.42e-08|8.72e-08/8.72e-08|1.57e-07/1.59e-07|1.61e-07/1.66e-07
  first|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|6.11e-08/6.11e-08|4.81e-08/4.81e-08|6.55e-08/6.55e-08|1.22e-07/1.22e-07|5.82e-08/5.82e-08
0x7+1  |
  zero |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.14e-07|1.66e-07/1.66e-07|1.09e-07/1.42e-07|1.83e-07/1.88e-07|2.05e-07/2.07e-07
  last |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.14e-07|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|1.83e-07/1.87e-07|1.92e-07/1.97e-07
  half |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.79e-07/1.81e-07|7.42e-08/7.42e-08|7.85e-08/7.86e-08|1.57e-07/1.61e-07|1.92e-07/1.97e-07
  first|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|6.11e-08/6.11e-08|4.81e-08/4.81e-08|5.24e-08/5.24e-08|1.22e-07/1.22e-07|6.55e-08/6.55e-08
0x7    |
  zero |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.14e-07|1.66e-07/1.71e-07|1.52e-07/1.79e-07|1.83e-07/1.88e-07|2.00e-07/2.06e-07
  last |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|2.09e-07/2.14e-07|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|1.44e-07/1.70e-07|1.83e-07/1.88e-07|1.83e-07/1.85e-07
  half |1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.79e-07/1.79e-07|7.42e-08/7.42e-08|7.85e-08/7.85e-08|1.57e-07/1.57e-07|1.39e-07/1.39e-07
  first|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|6.11e-08/6.11e-08|4.81e-08/4.81e-08|7.85e-08/7.85e-08|1.22e-07/1.22e-07|1.39e-07/1.39e-07
0x400  |
  zero |9.06e-06/9.06e-06|9.97e-06/9.97e-06|1.79e-05/1.81e-05|2.93e-06/2.93e-06|9.06e-06/9.07e-06|2.41e-06/2.41e-06
  last |9.06e-06/9.06e-06|9.97e-06/9.97e-06|1.80e-05/1.80e-05|2.39e-06/2.39e-06|9.06e-06/9.07e-06|2.40e-06/2.40e-06
  half |9.06e-06/9.06e-06|5.08e-06/5.08e-06|9.06e-06/9.06e-06|1.29e-06/1.29e-06|4.62e-06/4.62e-06|1.30e-06/1.30e-06
  first|9.06e-06/9.06e-06|9.25e-08/9.67e-08|8.34e-08/9.67e-08|1.05e-07/1.06e-07|1.58e-07/1.58e-07|1.75e-07/1.75e-07
0x1000 |
  zero |3.59e-05/3.59e-05|3.95e-05/3.95e-05|7.15e-05/7.15e-05|1.14e-05/1.14e-05|3.59e-05/3.59e-05|9.20e-06/9.20e-06
  last |3.59e-05/3.59e-05|3.95e-05/3.95e-05|3.59e-05/3.59e-05|9.18e-06/9.18e-06|3.59e-05/3.59e-05|9.19e-06/9.19e-06
  half |3.59e-05/3.59e-05|1.99e-05/1.99e-05|1.81e-05/1.81e-05|4.74e-06/4.74e-06|1.81e-05/1.81e-05|4.74e-06/4.75e-06
  first|3.59e-05/3.59e-05|2.04e-07/2.04e-07|2.04e-07/2.04e-07|2.13e-07/2.13e-07|2.65e-07/2.66e-07|2.82e-07/2.82e-07
0x10000|
  zero |9.52e-03/1.07e-02|1.14e-02/1.17e-02|1.94e-02/2.04e-02|3.43e-03/3.52e-03|9.59e-03/1.07e-02|3.10e-03/3.17e-03
  last |9.57e-03/1.07e-02|1.14e-02/1.17e-02|9.73e-03/1.08e-02|3.04e-03/3.13e-03|9.57e-03/1.05e-02|3.11e-03/3.22e-03
  half |9.54e-03/1.06e-02|5.06e-03/5.13e-03|4.69e-03/4.76e-03|1.17e-03/1.17e-03|4.60e-03/4.65e-03|1.18e-03/1.18e-03
  first|9.55e-03/1.07e-02|2.28e-06/2.29e-06|2.26e-06/2.27e-06|2.28e-06/2.29e-06|2.34e-06/2.35e-06|2.36e-06/2.36e-06
cc -m64 -g -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra  -o test64 test.c repe.S -lrt
./test64
       |          bit_or |      use_memcmp |     check_bytes |   check_aligned |      repe_scasb |       repe_scas
-------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
0x7+4  |
  zero |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.17e-07/1.17e-07|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|2.57e-07/2.67e-07
  last |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.04e-07/1.17e-07|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|1.70e-07/1.70e-07
  half |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.35e-07/1.35e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08|5.66e-08/5.66e-08|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08
  first|9.14e-08/9.14e-08|4.79e-08/4.79e-08|5.23e-08/5.23e-08|5.66e-08/5.66e-08|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08
0x7+2  |
  zero |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.17e-07/1.17e-07|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|2.30e-07/2.57e-07
  last |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.04e-07/1.04e-07|1.09e-07/1.09e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|2.22e-07/2.22e-07
  half |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.35e-07/1.35e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08|7.83e-08/7.83e-08|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.09e-07/1.09e-07
  first|9.14e-08/9.14e-08|4.79e-08/4.79e-08|5.23e-08/5.23e-08|5.66e-08/5.66e-08|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|7.40e-08/7.40e-08
0x7+1  |
  zero |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.17e-07/1.17e-07|1.17e-07/1.17e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|2.30e-07/2.32e-07
  last |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.04e-07/1.04e-07|1.04e-07/1.13e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07
  half |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.35e-07/1.35e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08|7.40e-08/7.40e-08|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07
  first|9.14e-08/9.14e-08|3.92e-08/3.92e-08|4.36e-08/4.36e-08|4.79e-08/4.79e-08|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08
0x7    |
  zero |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.17e-07/1.17e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|2.39e-07/2.65e-07
  last |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.65e-07/1.65e-07|1.04e-07/1.04e-07|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.52e-07/1.52e-07|1.70e-07/1.70e-07
  half |9.14e-08/9.14e-08|1.35e-07/1.35e-07|7.83e-08/7.83e-08|6.53e-08/6.53e-08|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|8.70e-08/8.70e-08
  first|9.14e-08/9.14e-08|4.79e-08/4.79e-08|5.23e-08/5.23e-08|6.53e-08/6.53e-08|1.00e-07/1.00e-07|8.70e-08/8.70e-08
0x400  |
  zero |9.04e-06/9.04e-06|9.90e-06/9.90e-06|9.03e-06/9.05e-06|2.36e-06/2.36e-06|9.01e-06/9.01e-06|1.25e-06/1.25e-06
  last |9.04e-06/9.04e-06|9.90e-06/9.90e-06|9.03e-06/9.03e-06|2.35e-06/2.35e-06|9.01e-06/9.01e-06|1.23e-06/1.23e-06
  half |9.04e-06/9.04e-06|5.02e-06/5.02e-06|4.59e-06/4.59e-06|1.25e-06/1.25e-06|4.57e-06/4.57e-06|6.84e-07/6.84e-07
  first|9.04e-06/9.04e-06|6.19e-08/7.47e-08|7.91e-08/7.92e-08|7.03e-08/7.05e-08|1.14e-07/1.15e-07|1.27e-07/1.28e-07
0x1000 |
  zero |3.61e-05/3.61e-05|3.93e-05/3.93e-05|3.58e-05/3.58e-05|9.08e-06/9.08e-06|3.58e-05/3.58e-05|4.64e-06/4.64e-06
  last |3.61e-05/3.61e-05|3.93e-05/3.93e-05|3.58e-05/3.58e-05|9.07e-06/9.07e-06|3.58e-05/3.58e-05|4.61e-06/4.61e-06
  half |3.61e-05/3.61e-05|1.97e-05/1.97e-05|1.80e-05/1.80e-05|4.63e-06/4.63e-06|1.80e-05/1.80e-05|2.40e-06/2.40e-06
  first|3.61e-05/3.61e-05|1.04e-07/1.17e-07|1.21e-07/1.21e-07|1.26e-07/1.26e-07|1.58e-07/1.58e-07|1.71e-07/1.71e-07
0x10000|
  zero |1.08e-02/1.09e-02|1.03e-02/1.04e-02|9.38e-03/9.50e-03|2.41e-03/2.49e-03|9.33e-03/9.50e-03|1.67e-03/1.73e-03
  last |1.08e-02/1.09e-02|1.03e-02/1.04e-02|9.38e-03/9.49e-03|2.44e-03/2.55e-03|9.33e-03/9.47e-03|1.62e-03/1.67e-03
  half |1.08e-02/1.10e-02|5.05e-03/5.12e-03|4.61e-03/4.69e-03|1.16e-03/1.16e-03|4.59e-03/4.66e-03|6.63e-04/6.65e-04
  first|1.08e-02/1.09e-02|8.70e-07/8.80e-07|8.70e-07/8.80e-07|8.90e-07/9.00e-07|9.60e-07/9.60e-07|9.70e-07/9.80e-07
$ uname -srvmp
Linux 2.6.32-gentoo #1 SMP Sun Dec 6 16:24:50 EST 2009 x86_64 AMD Phenom(tm) 9600 Quad-Core Processor
```

As you can see,

- for short data, simple is better
- memcmp is actually pretty good at crawling through memory (at least with whatever optimizations GCC 4.4.2 applies)
- x86's string intrinsics help a little
- the biggest gain on long data comes from taking larger strides — avoid byte-by-byte access if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another C++ solution:

```
bool all_zero( const char * buf, size_t len )
{
    return (buf == std::search_n( buf, buf+len, len, 0 ) );
}
```

search_n returns the first occurrence of a sequence of "len" consecutive occurrences of the value (here 0) or it returns "end". In this particular application it obviously either returns the start of the sequence or the end.

The advantage of this is I can also apply it to an array of ints, doubles, etc. which will be able to check word-by-word. (Obviously make all_zero a template to do that).

Comment: You should stop at the first occurrence of any non-zero-element. Your current solution will iterate over all elements in any cases.

Comment: Why do you think it will iterate over all the elements? It is up to the STL implementer to determine that. I am just showing how there is a straightforward STL call to check it, without having to use some weird functor to fit it into find_if.

Comment: If it will find non-zero element it'll just start counting from next element. Take a look at the paragraph 25.1.9/7 of the C++ Standard.

Comment: It might do if there are enough elements remaining from that point. But in this case if the first start position fails, there will not be enough elements in the range, so it would be wasteful to look at the next element.

Answer (score -1):

The function you want is called [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/).

Call it like this:

```
memset(pMem, '\0', iMemSize);
```

Comment: Sorry, my ques how to judge the content of the memory