# Check if a struct is empty

Tags: c++, memset

I have an old piece of code with a big struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
 long test1;
 char test2[10]
 …
} teststruct;
```

This struct gets initialized like this:

```
memset(teststruct, 0, sizeof(teststruct0));
```

I must not change this code in any way. How do I efficiently check if the struct is empty, or has been modified after the `memset()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? It has member variables, so it cannot be empty. Do you mean to check if all the values are still set to 0?

Comment: Have a boolean flag that you set to true if you set some values in the structure? And if that's not possible, `memcmp` with a structure which is "empty"?

Comment: What do you mean by "struct is empty"

Comment: You can `memcmp` with an array of zeros of the same size.

Comment: Why `memset`? Btw, `teststruct` is not an instance. It's a _type_ so `memset(teststruct, 0, sizeof(teststruct));` is utterly wrong.

Comment: I need to check if no entries have been changed since the memset, thats what I mean with „empty“.

Comment: @molbdnilo But `memset` will also set the padding.

Comment: I am not allowed to make a boolean flag. This above was just an example, the actual struct type has over 600 lines and is about 20 years old.

Comment: @Zeta Is it compiled with a C++98 compiler? How is it instantiated and how is `memset` really used?

Comment: Is `test2` a null terminated C string or just an array of 10 `char`s (not forming a string)?

Comment: Can you show the actual code? The code you posted cannot work, since teststruct is a typedef and not a variable. You can leave out all the lines in the struct, but please show the rest.

Comment: The code was originally written in Pascal and later on ported to C++. Now it gets compiled with a C++11 compiler. The memset is used exactly as stated above with an instance of the struct. I must not change the struct and the memset since this code is used in a very critical application and must not be changed by anyone.

Comment: test2 is forming a c string

Comment: "_The memset is used exactly as stated above_" - no, that will not compile since you have put a _type_ where a pointer to memory should have been put.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I forgot that I already got a pointer here, I just copied it off 1:1 and changed the names.

Comment: A lot of these comments feel needlessly pedantic or irrelevant to the question at hand. Since you are unable to store an additional modified flag, can this question be restated as checking if the current contents of a given `teststruct` are identical to that of a new `teststruct` directly after being initialized with `memset`?

Comment: Update the question instead of explaining in the comment section

Comment: @Zeta If you've set `test2` to something, like `teststruct i; memset(&i, 0, sizeof i); strcpy(i.test2, "Hello");` and then set it back to a blank string: `strcpy(i.test2, "");` should `i` now be considered _empty_ again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to find out if this struct has any non-zero values. As you can see in the comments, there are a couple exceptions you may want to consider, but for the simple solution we can copy this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563801/5987669).

```c
// Checks if all bytes in a teststruct are zero
bool is_empty(teststruct *data) {
    unsigned char *mm = (unsigned char*) data;
    return (*mm == 0) && memcmp(mm, mm + 1, sizeof(teststruct) - 1) == 0;
}
```